# ciclo de repetiçao For encadeado, em C # sharp, iniciaçao

Tags: c#, for

Olá, boa tarde alguém me consegue corrigir o programa para estar certo? O objetivo é o programa em c sharp escreve está pronto para receber a reforma, caso tenha mais de 60 anos e mais de 30 anos de trabalho. Estou a falhar em algo e nao consigo descobrir, obrigado.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool val;
            int codigo, idade, trab, anonascim, anoingres;
            int anoatual=2020;

        do // ler e validar o codigo do empregado
        {
            Console.Write("\n\t Insira o codigo do empregado");
            val = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine(), out codigo);

        }
        while (!val);


        for (int i = 0; i <codigo ; i++)
        {
            do
            {
                Console.Write("\n\t Insira o ano de nascimento do empregado");
                val = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine(), out anonascim);
                Console.Write("\n\t Insira o ano de ingresso na empresa");
                val = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine(), out anoingres);

             }
            while (!val);
        }


        if (idade > 64 || trab > 29)
        {
            for (int idade = 0; idade > 64; idade++)
            {
                idade = (anoatual - anonascim);

                Console.Write($"\t com {idade} ");

                for (int trab = 0; trab > 29; trab++)
                {

                    trab = (anoatual - anoingres);
                    Console.Write($"\t com {trab} ");
                }

            }
        }

                    Console.WriteLine($"\n\t Esta em condicoes de requerer a reforma :{i}, codigo");

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"\n\t Nao esta em condicoes de requerer a reforma ");

            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Qual o erro específico que está acontecendo?

Answer (score 0):

Olá, tudo bem? De acordo com a sua descrição, caso a pessoa tenha 64 anos ou mais e tenha trabalhado por 29 anos ou mais ela pode requerer a reforma. Com base nisso, refiz o seu código.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool val;
        int codigo, idade, trab, anonascim, anoingres;
        int anoatual=2020;

    do // ler e validar o codigo do empregado
    {
        Console.Write("\n\t Insira o codigo do empregado");
        val = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine(), out codigo);

    }
    while (!val);

        do
        {
            Console.Write("\n\t Insira o ano de nascimento do empregado");
            val = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine(), out anonascim);
            Console.Write("\n\t Insira o ano de ingresso na empresa");
            val = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine(), out anoingres);

         }
        while (!val);

           idade = (anoatual - anonascim);
           trab = (anoatual - anoingres);

            Console.Write($"\t com {idade} ");
            Console.Write($"\t com {trab} ");
            
            if(idade >= 64 && trab >= 29){
            Console.WriteLine($"\n\t Esta em condicoes de requerer a reforma :{i}, codigo");}

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\n\t Nao esta em condicoes de requerer a reforma ");}}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  bool val,val1;
```

[...]

```
do
   {
        Console.Write("\n\t Insira o ano de nascimento do empregado");
        val = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out anonascim);
        Console.Write("\n\t Insira o ano de ingresso na empresa");
        val1 = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out anoingres);

     }
    while (!val && !va1);
```